# How to validate entire JSON with 1 dynamic field with JMeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I have a JSR223 Assertion in JMeter that validates entire JSON response and its working. 
The problem is that each time I insert data in DB one of JSON fields changes and validation fails.

How could I skip that dynamic field from response validation?

Response JSON example:

```
[
  {
    "id": "273444",
    "trxDateTime": "2019-03-25T22:38:16Z",
    "merchantName": "MerchECOM1",
    "merchantTransId": "1r1vXue4qn",
    "trxType": "Payment",
    "paymentBrand": "MasterCard",
    "amount": 20.00,
    "currencyCode": "AUD",
    "status": "Declined",
    "statusResponseMessage": null,
    "customerAccount": "123456"
  }
]
```

JSR223 Assertion:

```
def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('expected1'))
def actual = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

if (expected != actual) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between expected and actual JSON')
}
```

just with this I'm not able to validate the dynamic "id" field

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not interested in this `id` field - just **remove** it from the expected variable and the actual response, to wit amend first 2 lines of your assertion to look like:

```
def expected = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('expected1')).each {entry -> entry.remove('id')}
def actual = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).each {entry -> entry.remove('id')}
```

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If value is not your concern for id field you can directly use regex matcher to check the field using Jsonassertion by specifying jsonpath and check match as regex use regex

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution (probably the best) but my question is about how to skip one field in a JSON matching